# python: compare data of different date types

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, compare

I have a question of comparing data of datetime64[ns] and date like '2017-01-01'.

here is the code:
`df.loc[(df['Date'] >= datetime.date(2017.1.1), 'TimeRange'] = '2017.1'`

but , an error has been showed and said `descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'.`

how can i compare a datetime64 to data (2017-01-01 or 2-17-6-1 and likes)

Thanks

Comment: you should transform your date to have the same type to be able to compare it you can for example see this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: Your code has a syntax error (unclosed `(` before `df['Date']`).  Please post the code that results in the particular error along with the traceback.

Comment: Thank you, @Dadep. great reference.

Comment: Thank you, ＠Billy, i have already resolved this issue. Thank you for telling me this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo:

Source DF:

```
In [83]: df = pd.DataFrame({'tm':pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='9999T', periods=20)})

In [84]: df
Out[84]:
                    tm
0  2000-01-01 00:00:00
1  2000-01-07 22:39:00
2  2000-01-14 21:18:00
3  2000-01-21 19:57:00
4  2000-01-28 18:36:00
5  2000-02-04 17:15:00
6  2000-02-11 15:54:00
7  2000-02-18 14:33:00
8  2000-02-25 13:12:00
9  2000-03-03 11:51:00
10 2000-03-10 10:30:00
11 2000-03-17 09:09:00
12 2000-03-24 07:48:00
13 2000-03-31 06:27:00
14 2000-04-07 05:06:00
15 2000-04-14 03:45:00
16 2000-04-21 02:24:00
17 2000-04-28 01:03:00
18 2000-05-04 23:42:00
19 2000-05-11 22:21:00
```

Filtering:

```
In [85]: df.loc[df.tm > '2000-03-01']
Out[85]:
                    tm
9  2000-03-03 11:51:00
10 2000-03-10 10:30:00
11 2000-03-17 09:09:00
12 2000-03-24 07:48:00
13 2000-03-31 06:27:00
14 2000-04-07 05:06:00
15 2000-04-14 03:45:00
16 2000-04-21 02:24:00
17 2000-04-28 01:03:00
18 2000-05-04 23:42:00
19 2000-05-11 22:21:00

In [86]: df.loc[df.tm > '2000-3-1']
Out[86]:
                    tm
9  2000-03-03 11:51:00
10 2000-03-10 10:30:00
11 2000-03-17 09:09:00
12 2000-03-24 07:48:00
13 2000-03-31 06:27:00
14 2000-04-07 05:06:00
15 2000-04-14 03:45:00
16 2000-04-21 02:24:00
17 2000-04-28 01:03:00
18 2000-05-04 23:42:00
19 2000-05-11 22:21:00
```

not standard date format:

```
In [87]: df.loc[df.tm > pd.to_datetime('03/01/2000')]
Out[87]:
                    tm
9  2000-03-03 11:51:00
10 2000-03-10 10:30:00
11 2000-03-17 09:09:00
12 2000-03-24 07:48:00
13 2000-03-31 06:27:00
14 2000-04-07 05:06:00
15 2000-04-14 03:45:00
16 2000-04-21 02:24:00
17 2000-04-28 01:03:00
18 2000-05-04 23:42:00
19 2000-05-11 22:21:00
```

Comment: Thank you, very easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that the data you're comparing it with is also in the same format. Assuming that you have two `datetime` objects, you can do it like this:

```
import datetime
print(df.loc[(df['Date'] >= datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 'TimeRange'])
```

This will create a `datetime` object and list out the filtered results. You can also assign the results an updated value as you have mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you, very easy to understand.